# How to create columns of words that are before and after a certain keyword in R?

Tags: r, regex, text, tidyverse, multiple-columns

My input is a csv file that has the following table with Sentence and Class columns.

```
Sentence                            Class
Joe just joined Alice on the set.   B
Alexis buys green apples            C
Yesterday, two friends unite.       A
Combination between x and y!        A
```

Each class has a list of ranked words.(Not in csv)

```
Class A keyword list    Class B keyword list    Class C keyword list
unite                   joined                  buy
combination             join                    buys
together                merge                   bought
```

My output needs to be a csv with added columns of the words that come before and after the highest ranked keyword, from the class keyword list, found in that Sentence.(See pic below)

[image]

Notice that there are empty spaces in certain columns because the corresponding word does not exist in that sentence.

How do I do this in R?

Comment: 1. Make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Provide data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy preferably using `dput`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). 2. What have you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you imported the files and converted to the following formats:

```r
df <- tribble(
  ~ Sentence, ~ Class,
  "Joe just joined Alice on the set.", "B",
  "Alexis buys green apples", "C",
  "Yesterday, two friends unite.", "A",
  "Combination between x and y!", "A"
)

kw_list <- list(
  A=c("unite", "combination", "together"),
  B=c("joined", "join", "merge"),
  C=c("buy", "buys", "bought")
)
```

Then you can obtain a data frame specified in the image as follows:

```r
result <- df %>% mutate(res=map2(Sentence, Class, function(sentence, class){
  word_list <- sentence %>% str_replace_all("[(,)(\\.)(!)]", "") %>%
    str_split(" ") %>% .[[1]] %>% str_to_lower()
  kws <- word_list %>% c(kw_list[[class]]) %>% .[duplicated(.)]
  if(length(kws)==0){
    return(NA)
  }else{
    kws %>% map(function(kw){
      position <- str_which(word_list, str_c("^", kw, "$"))
      left_kw <- if(position!=1){
        word_list[1:(position-1)] %>% rev() %>% .[1:3] %>%
          tibble(name=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd") %>% str_c(" word from left"), value=.) %>%
          arrange(desc(name)) %>% pivot_wider()
      }else{
        NULL
      }
      right_kw <- if(position!=length(word_list)){
        word_list[(position+1):length(word_list)] %>% .[1:3] %>%
          tibble(name=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd") %>% str_c(" word from right"), value=.) %>%
          pivot_wider()
      }else{
        NULL
      }
      bind_cols(left_kw, tibble(`key word`=kw), right_kw)
    }) %>% reduce(bind_rows) %>% return()
  }
})) %>% unnest(cols=res)
```

This can deal with sentences which include several keywords and those which do not include any of the keywords.
Please be reminded that all letters are changed to lower case, and it would not work well if symbols other than `,.!` is included.

Definitely this is a bit too lengthy and not the best solution, but hope it helps.